# Unique IP per celeryd instance on single machine?

Tags: ip, celery

I am running a series of tasks using Celery and RabbitMQ which quickly reaches the rate limits of websites the tasks request from. I was wondering if it's possible to bind an instance of celeryd to an public IP address and have multiple instances running on the same machine?

I do have multiple public IP addresses I can use but I have very little experience with networking.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do what you want to do by running several celeryd instances and binding each to an IP using a shim. See [here](https://superuser.com/a/271949).

Another option would be to just assign the additional IPs to your network card using `ifconfig` and let the OS send the traffic over whatever IP it chooses to. According to [this](http://linux.m2osw.com/two_ips_on_one_nic) you should get a distribution of traffic across the different IPs. Downside: no control which IP is used by which process.

Hope that helps